# How might I create a SharePoint 2010 content query web part programatically?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How might I create a SharePoint 2010 content query web part programatically and add it to a SharePoint page?

Comment: There's a lot of articles and blog post describing this task - I posted one of them as an answer below. Can you make your question more specific? Are you facing any particular problem?

Answer (score 0):

The post [Adding/Removing web part in SharePoint website programmatically using C# code](http://www.etechplanet.com/blog/addingremoving-web-part-programmatically-in-sharepoint-website-using-c-code.aspx) contains a detailed description of adding and removing Web Parts.

Here's a snippet taken from the above post adding a Web Part to a page (replace the `WebPartToBeAdded` pseudoclass with `ContentByQueryWebPart`):

```
using (SPSite spSiteTest = new SPSite(“SiteURL”) 
{   
   using (SPWeb spWebTest = spSiteTest.OpenWeb())   
   {     
     SPWebPartCollection webparts = spWebTest.GetWebPartCollection("WebPageURL",Storage.Shared);      

     //create new webpart object           
     WebPartToBeAdded wpNew = new WebPartToBeAdded();      

     //set properties of new webpart object     
     wpNew.ZoneID = "WebPartZoneIDWhereWebPartIsToBeAdded";     
     wpNew.Title = "Web Part Title";     
     wpNew.ChromeState = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeState.Normal;     
     wpNew.ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.None;      

     //add new webpart object to webparts collection     
     webparts.Add(wpNew);      

     //update spWeb object     
     spWebTest.Update();    
   } 
}
```